# Calculate employee costs using a date filter in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a measurement that allows me to sum up total employee costs. I have an employee table with employee's start and end date (end date is null if still employed), I have a salary history table with employeeid, samount, whether the amount is annual or hourly, hours worked per week and the salary start and end date (end date is null if salary is still active).

I managed to calculate **salary_per_hour** and add it to the salary history table that takes into account how they are paid, hours worked per week, holiday allowance and national bank holidays.

However, I am struggling to get an accurate cost over a dynamic date range. At the moment I have tried a few things, but this is the closest:

```
EmployeeTotalCostInRange = 
CALCULATE(
    SUMX(
        VALUES(Salaries[employee_id]),
        CALCULATE(
            (
                MAX(Salaries[salary_per_hour]) * 7.5 * COUNTROWS(
                    FILTER(
                        'Dates_Table',
                        'Dates_Table'[Date] >= MIN(Salaries[salaries.start_date])
                        && ('Dates_Table'[Date] <= MAX(Salaries[salaries.end_date]) || ISBLANK(MAX(Salaries[salaries.end_date])))
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

*The 7.5 is assuming everyone works 7.5 hours in a day.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a stab in the dark here, but hopefully it will inspire some new thinking:

```
EmployeeTotalCostInRange = 
  CALCULATE(
    SUMX(
      VALUES(Salaries[employee_id]),
      CALCULATE(
        MAX(Salaries[salary_per_hour]) * 7.5 * DATEDIFF(
          MAX(
            MIN(Salaries[salaries.start_date]) ,
            MIN('Dates_Table'[Date])
          ),
          MIN(
            COALESCE( MAX(Salaries[salaries.start_date]), TODAY())
            MAX('Dates_Table'[Date])
          ),
          DAY
        )
      )
    )
  )
```